# Pop-up window for a related layer doesn't show the right values in ArcGIS online

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, relates

In my ArcGIS online map, I have two layers (*morminte* and *layer2*) related in a *one-to-many* relationship. For an item from the ***morminte*** layer I can have 0, one or two corresponding values from ***layer2***. In the picture below it is shown the pop-up window for an item from **morminte**. In the pop-up,
only the **Nr. Mormant** field is from the *morminte* layer. This is the only field that returns the right value.

The rest of the fields are from the related layer. 
The fields NUME (surname) and PRENUME (name) should return text values, DATA_NASTERII and DATA_DECES -> date values and VARSTA->a number. Instead, if for the selected item I have one corresponding value from layer2, the pop-up returns "1", if I have 2 corresponding values, then I get "2" and if there is no value to be related, then I get "0".

[image]

Before uploading the map to ArcGIS Online, I made sure that both layers involved in the relationship class are configured properly in ArcMap. NUME and PRENUME are string fields, DATA_DECES and DATA_NASTERII are date fields and VARSTA is a short integer field.

In the **Configure Attributes** window for the **morminte** layer, I noticed that I can select only  *count* in the *Statistic Operator* tab. I don't know if it has something to do with this.

[image]

I also created a layer that has the fields NUME, PRENUME etc. as it's own. In this case, the pop-up shows the right values. But in my map I want to use two  related layers instead of one because is more advantageous for what I need to do.

Answer (score 3):

Those values that you see are just statistics on the fields and not actual attributes. If you want to see the attributes you will need to click on "Show Related Records" at the bottom of the popups. This will load the table with the related records associated with that feature. We are working on improving this popup interaction with related records and supporting viewing attachments in associated with related records.

Comment: Correct show related records will only display the data in a table. The table data is not editable in ArcGIS Online today. Currently if you wanted to edit related table data it would have to be done in Desktop or Collector for ArcGIS.

Comment: The related records will always be displayed in the table form and not in the popup. The issue you mentioned above is referring to the data you want displayed in the popup. Any related record attribute data will always be displayed in the table and be read only. If you check on the related record fields in the popup they are just statistic fields. https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_09B2E0D22072457AAC8D025377DD7CF9

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still having this issue or not, but the issue is with the relationship class. If you set up a 1-to-many relationship, the attribute will not show in the pop-up, it will only show the count of related records. If you want the attributes to populate in the pop-up, the relationship must be set up as a 1-to-1 link (or many-to-1).

http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm

(see the 'Show Related Data' section)

Here is the relevant info you are looking for...

> With a one-to-one relationship, the pop-up displays the related
>   attributes within the pop-up window. With a one-to-many relationship,
>   choose to display the related data within the pop-up window or in a
>   table. When displaying attributes within the pop-up, string fields
>   show the count. For numeric fields, you can choose to display the sum,
>   min, max, average, or count.